# spark date format MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to timestamp in df

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert a descriptive date format from a log file "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM" to the spark timestamp datatype. I tried something like below, but it is giving null.

```
val df = Seq(("Nov 05, 2018 02:46:47 AM"),("Nov 5, 2018 02:46:47 PM")).toDF("times")
df.withColumn("time2",date_format('times,"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss AM")).show(false)

+------------------------+-----+
|times                   |time2|
+------------------------+-----+
|Nov 05, 2018 02:46:47 AM|null |
|Nov 5, 2018 02:46:47 PM |null |
+------------------------+-----+
```

Expected output

```
+------------------------+----------------------------+
|times                   |time2                       |
+------------------------+-----+----------------------+
|Nov 05, 2018 02:46:47 AM|2018-11-05 02:46:47.000000" |
|Nov 5, 2018 02:46:47 PM |2018-11-05 14:46:47.000000" |
+------------------------+-----+----------------------+
```

What is the proper format for converting this?. Note that DD may be having leading zeroes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is your answer

```
val df = Seq(("Nov 05, 2018 02:46:47 AM"),("Nov 5, 2018 02:46:47 PM")).toDF("times")

scala> df.withColumn("times2", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("times"), "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")).show(false)
    +------------------------+--------------------------+
    |times                   |times2                    |
    +------------------------+--------------------------+
    |Nov 05, 2018 02:46:47 AM|2018-11-05 02:46:47.000000|
    |Nov 5, 2018 02:46:47 PM |2018-11-05 14:46:47.000000|
    +------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Please use hh for hour instead of HH if you want to parse 12 hour format. Also am/pm is indicated by suffix "a" while parsing.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Using to_timestamp and date_format functions

```
scala> df.withColumn("times2",to_timestamp('times,"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a")).show(false)
+------------------------+-------------------+
|times                   |times2             |
+------------------------+-------------------+
|Nov 05, 2018 02:46:47 AM|2018-11-05 02:46:47|
|Nov 5, 2018 02:46:47 PM |2018-11-05 14:46:47|
+------------------------+-------------------+


scala> df.withColumn("times2",date_format(to_timestamp('times,"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")).show(false)
+------------------------+--------------------------+
|times                   |times2                    |
+------------------------+--------------------------+
|Nov 05, 2018 02:46:47 AM|2018-11-05 02:46:47.000000|
|Nov 5, 2018 02:46:47 PM |2018-11-05 14:46:47.000000|
+------------------------+--------------------------+


scala>
```

Comment: Hey I am using the above code in my pysaprk, but its giving me null values

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL syntax:

```
select date_format(to_timestamp(ColumnTimestamp, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"), "yyyy-MM-dd") as ColumnDate 
from database_name.table_name
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `splitby`

```
Select date.split('-')[2]||'-'||case when length(date.split('-')[0]) = 1 then '0'||date.split('-')[0] else  date.split('-')[0] end  || case when length(date.split('-')[1]) = 1 then '0'||date.split('-')[1] else  date.split('-')[1] end] 
Date = date_column
```

Date format `yyyy-mm-dd`
Delimiter can be different.

Without any date format

Comment: it might work, but a laborious task..